# How do I do my homework with Arrays, Functions and Binary Search?

Tags: java, arrays, function

So basically what I want to do is a program that asks the user how big he wants his array to be and for the user to introduce the values inside the array. Then I want the user to be able to introduce a number and for the program to determine in which array the number is or determine that it doesn't exist. The following program currently generates the values of the arrays randomly and the user introduces how many array elements he wants to use. But I don't know how to make this in to what I previously explained.

```
package laboratorio9;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArregloBinario
{
    private int[] datos;
    private static Random generador = new Random();

    public ArregloBinario (int tamanio)
    {
        datos = new int[tamanio];

        for (int i=0; i<tamanio; i++)
            datos[i] = 10 + generador.nextInt(90);

        Arrays.sort(datos);
    }

    public int busquedaBinaria(int elementoBusqueda)
    {
        int inferior = 0;
        int superior = datos.length-1;
        int medio = (inferior + superior + 1 ) / 2;
        int ubicacion = -1;

        // **HOW CAN I CHANGE THE FOLLOWING NTO A RECURSIVE FUNCTION>**
        do 
        {
            System.out.print(elementosRestantes(inferior,superior));

            for (int i = 0; i<medio; i++)
                System.out.print("  ");
            System.out.println(" * ");

            if (elementoBusqueda == datos[medio])
                ubicacion=medio;
            else if (elementoBusqueda<datos[medio])
                superior = medio-1;
            else 
                inferior = medio+1;

            medio = (inferior + superior + 1) / 2;
        } while ((inferior <=superior) && (ubicacion == -1));
        return ubicacion;                
    }

    public String elementosRestantes(int inferior, int superior)
    {
        StringBuilder temporal = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < inferior; i++)
            temporal.append( "  " );

        for (int i = inferior; i <= superior; i++)
            temporal.append( datos[i] + " ");

        temporal.append("\n");
        return temporal.toString();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return elementosRestantes(0, datos.length-1);
    }
}

// MAIN CLASS //

package laboratorio9;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaBusquedaBinaria {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        int enteroABuscar;
        int posicion;

        System.out.println("Please write the number of elements in the array.");
        int number = entrada.nextInt();

        ArregloBinario arregloBusqueda = new ArregloBinario(number);
        System.out.println(arregloBusqueda);

        System.out.print("Write a value (-1) to go out: ");
        enteroABuscar = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        while (enteroABuscar != -1)
        {
            posicion = arregloBusqueda.busquedaBinaria(enteroABuscar);

            if (posicion==-1)
                System.out.println("The value " + enteroABuscar + " was not found.\n");
            else
                System.out.println("The value " + enteroABuscar +
                        " was found in position " + posicion + ".\n");

            System.out.print(
                    "Write a number (-1 to go out): ");
            enteroABuscar = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to do?  We aren't going to just do your homework for you... you are better off asking "I cannot get this thing that I tried to do to work? and show us the code that you tried to do the recursion with.

Comment: I just a couple of questions for clarification:
How do you want the user to provide the values?
Is the purpose to create a recursive search rather than one in a loop?

Comment: What you have above is an "iterative" binary search. There are lots of resources out there in Google comparing iterative with recursive binary search - go and take a look, have go at replacing the do/while loop, and post what you come up with. If you still need help, everyone will pitch in. Deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, here is the original ArregloBinario class with the spacing fixed up:

```
package laboratorio9;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArregloBinario
{
    private int[] datos;
    private static Random generador = new Random();

    public ArregloBinario (int tamanio)
    {
        datos = new int[tamanio];

        for (int i=0; i<tamanio; i++)
            datos[i] = 10 + generador.nextInt(90);

        Arrays.sort(datos);
    }

    public int busquedaBinaria(int elementoBusqueda)
    {
        int inferior = 0;
        int superior = datos.length-1;
        int medio = (inferior + superior + 1 ) / 2;
        int ubicacion = -1;

        // **HOW CAN I CHANGE THE FOLLOWING NTO A RECURSIVE FUNCTION>**
        do 
        {
            System.out.print(elementosRestantes(inferior,superior));

            for (int i = 0; i<medio; i++)
                System.out.print("   ");
            System.out.println(" * ");

            if (elementoBusqueda == datos[medio])
                ubicacion=medio;
            else if (elementoBusqueda<datos[medio])
                superior = medio-1;
            else 
                inferior = medio+1;

            medio = (inferior + superior + 1) / 2;
        } while ((inferior <=superior) && (ubicacion == -1));
        return ubicacion;                
    }

    public String elementosRestantes(int inferior, int superior)
    {
        StringBuilder temporal = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < inferior; i++)
            temporal.append( "   " );

        for (int i = inferior; i <= superior; i++)
            temporal.append( datos[i] + " ");

        temporal.append("\n");
        return temporal.toString();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return elementosRestantes(0, datos.length-1);
    }
}
```

And here's a recursive version:

```
package laboratorio9;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArregloBinario
{
    private int[] datos;
    private static Random generador = new Random();

    public ArregloBinario (int tamanio)
    {
        datos = new int[tamanio];

        for (int i=0; i<tamanio; i++)
            datos[i] = 10 + generador.nextInt(90);

        Arrays.sort(datos);
    }

    private int recursive (int elem, int inf, int sup, int med) {
        System.out.print(elementosRestantes(inf,sup));

        for (int i = 0; i<med; i++)
            System.out.print("   ");
        System.out.println(" * ");

        if (inf > sup)
            return -1;

        if (elem == datos[med])
            return med;

        if (elem<datos[med])
            return recursive (elem,inf,med-1,(inf + med) / 2);

    return recursive (elem,med+1,sup,(med + sup + 2) / 2);
    }

    public int busquedaBinaria(int elementoBusqueda)
    {
        int inf = 0;
        int sup = datos.length-1;
        int med = (inf + sup + 1 ) / 2;
        int ubi = -1;

        return recursive (elementoBusqueda,inf,sup,med);
    }

    public String elementosRestantes(int inferior, int superior)
    {
        StringBuilder temporal = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < inferior; i++)
            temporal.append( "   " );

        for (int i = inferior; i <= superior; i++)
            temporal.append( datos[i] + " ");

        temporal.append("\n");
        return temporal.toString();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return elementosRestantes(0, datos.length-1);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample run under Eclipse as the intensive testing it underwent :-)

```
Please write the number of elements in the array.
20
14 18 19 20 22 31 43 50 55 58 58 59 62 71 72 74 85 92 95 98 

Write a value (-1) to go out: 95
14 18 19 20 22 31 43 50 55 58 58 59 62 71 72 74 85 92 95 98 
                               * 
                                 59 62 71 72 74 85 92 95 98 
                                              * 
                                                85 92 95 98 
                                                       * 
The value 95 was found in position 18.

Write a number (-1 to go out): -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int randomNums[];
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = myScanner.nextInt();

        //create the array with length determined from input
        randomNums = new int[len];

        //populates the array with random numbers
        for(int y=0;y<len;y++)
        {
            randomNums[y] = (int)(Math.random()*50+1);
            System.out.println(randomNums[y]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(randomNums);
        int index=0;
        while(true)
        {
            int searchFor = myScanner.nextInt();
            //input of -1 will end search
            if (searchFor==-1)
                break;
            else
            {
                 index = rBinarySearch(randomNums,0,len,searchFor); 
            }
            if (index==-1)
                System.out.println("not found");
            else
                System.out.println("the element was found at index: " + index);
        }
    }

    public static int rBinarySearch(int[] sorted, int first, int upto, int key) {

        if (first < upto) {
            int mid = first + (upto - first) / 2;  // Compute mid point.
            if (key < sorted[mid]) {
                return rBinarySearch(sorted, first, mid, key);

            } else if (key > sorted[mid]) {
                return rBinarySearch(sorted, mid+1, upto , key);

            } else {
                return mid;   // Found it.
            }
        }
        return -(first + 1);  // Failed to find key
    }
}
```